# How to get shared preference value from baseadaptor to activity

Tags: android, gridview, sharedpreferences, android-gridview

Selecting multiple items from custom list view and passing to another
list view. When I close the application, these selected items are getting clean.

> I have used shared preference ,I could not able to get the data>
>    MainActivity

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Button bt_inst_app;
GridView gridView, gv_shortcut;
List<AppList> installedApps;
List<AppList> res = new ArrayList<AppList>();
private String appName, appPackageName;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    gv_shortcut = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gv_shortcut);
    bt_inst_app = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_inst_app);
    bt_inst_app.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder quick_links_alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            quick_links_alert.setTitle("Edit Quick Links");
            LinearLayout quick_links_layout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
            quick_links_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams quick_links_layoutparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            quick_links_layoutparams.setMargins(20, 0, 30, 0);
            gridView = new GridView(MainActivity.this);
            installedApps = getInstalledApps();
            final GridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, installedApps);
            gridView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
            gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
            gridView.setNumColumns(5);
            quick_links_alert.setView(gridView);
            quick_links_alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    final List<AppList> mArrayProducts = gridViewAdapter.getCheckedItems();
                    final QuickLinksGridViewAdaptor selected_apps = new QuickLinksGridViewAdaptor(MainActivity.this, mArrayProducts);
                    gv_shortcut.setAdapter(selected_apps);
                    gv_shortcut.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            String s = mArrayProducts.get(position).getPackageName();
                            Intent PackageManagerIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(s);//Here some time getting NULL
                            startActivity(PackageManagerIntent);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                }
            });
            quick_links_alert.show();

        }

        private List<AppList> getInstalledApps() {
            List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
                PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
                //if ((isSystemPackage(p) == false)) {
                if (((p.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) != true) {
                    appName = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
                    Drawable icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
                    appPackageName = p.applicationInfo.packageName;
                    res.add(new AppList(icon, appName, appPackageName));
                }
            }
            return res;
        }
    });
}
}
```

**GridViewAdapter.java**

```
   public class GridViewAdapter<T> extends BaseAdapter {
Context mContext;
//private final int length = 9;*/
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
List<AppList> listStorage;
MainActivity homeactivity;
private int selectedIndex;
private int selectedColor = Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b");
SparseBooleanArray mSparseBooleanArray;
SharedPreferences settings;
public GridViewAdapter(Context context, List<AppList> customizedListView) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.mContext = context;
    listStorage = customizedListView;
    mSparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
}
public void setSelectedIndex(int ind) {
    selectedIndex = ind;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public ArrayList<T> getCheckedItems() {
    ArrayList<T> mTempArry = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listStorage.size(); i++) {
        if (mSparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
            mTempArry.add((T) listStorage.get(i));
        }
    }
    return mTempArry;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listStorage.size();
}
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listStorage.get(position);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder listViewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        listViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.add_apps_grid_item, parent, false);
        listViewHolder.textInListView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        listViewHolder.imageInListView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_type);
        listViewHolder.tvPkgName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPack);
        listViewHolder.select_app = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.select_app);
        convertView.setTag(listViewHolder);
    } else {
        listViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    listViewHolder.textInListView.setText(listStorage.get(position).getName());
    listViewHolder.imageInListView.setImageDrawable(listStorage.get(position).getIcon());
    listViewHolder.tvPkgName.setText(listStorage.get(position).getPackageName());
    listViewHolder.select_app.setTag(position);
    listViewHolder.select_app.setChecked(mSparseBooleanArray.get(position));
    final AppList item = listStorage.get(position);
    listViewHolder.textInListView.setText(item.getName());
    SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean Checked = settings.getBoolean(item.getName(), false);
    listViewHolder.select_app.setChecked(Checked);
    listViewHolder.select_app.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "pkg name==" + listStorage.get(position).getPackageName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (listViewHolder.select_app.isChecked() == true) {
                SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
               // Toast.makeText(mContext, "You deselected " + Context.MODE_PRIVATE, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), settings.edit().putBoolean(item.getName(), true).commit());
               // Toast.makeText(mContext, "You selected " + item.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), settings.edit().putBoolean(item.getName(), false).commit());
               // Toast.makeText(mContext, "You deselected " + item.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
           // Toast.makeText(mContext, "Shared prefernce---->" + mContext.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
OnCheckedChangeListener mCheckedChangeListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                 boolean isChecked) {
        mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
    }

};
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView textInListView, tvPkgName;
    ImageView imageInListView;
    CheckBox select_app;
}
 }
```

**AppList.java**

```
public class AppList implements Parcelable {
private String name;
private String packageName;
Drawable icon;
private boolean selected;

public AppList(Drawable icon, String name, String packageName) {
    this.name = name;
    this.icon = icon;
    this.packageName = packageName;
}
protected AppList(Parcel in) {
    name = in.readString();
    packageName = in.readString();
    selected = in.readByte() != 0;
}
public static final Creator<AppList> CREATOR = new Creator<AppList>() {
    @Override
    public AppList createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new AppList(in);
    }

    @Override
    public AppList[] newArray(int size) {
        return new AppList[size];
    }
};
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public String getPackageName() {
    return packageName;
}
public Drawable getIcon() {
    return icon;
}
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(name);
    parcel.writeString(packageName);
    parcel.writeByte((byte) (selected ? 1 : 0));
}
public boolean isSelected() {
    return selected;
}
public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}
 }
```

**QuickLinksGridViewAdaptor.java**

```
public class QuickLinksGridViewAdaptor<T> extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
//private final int length = 9;*/
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
List<AppList> listStorage;
MainActivity homeactivity;
private int selectedIndex;
SparseBooleanArray mSparseBooleanArray;
int num = 1;
public QuickLinksGridViewAdaptor(Context context, List<AppList> customizedListView) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    listStorage = customizedListView;
    mSparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
}
public void setSelectedIndex(int ind) {
    selectedIndex = ind;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public ArrayList<T> getCheckedItems() {
    ArrayList<T> mTempArry = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listStorage.size(); i++) {
        if (mSparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
            mTempArry.add((T) listStorage.get(i));
        }
    }
    return mTempArry;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    //return 8;
    if(num*8 >= listStorage.size()){
        return listStorage.size();
    }else{
        return num*8;
    }
}
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listStorage.get(position);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder listViewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        listViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_apps_grid_item1, parent, false);
        listViewHolder.textInListView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name1);
        listViewHolder.imageInListView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_type1);
        convertView.setTag(listViewHolder);

    } else {
        listViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    listViewHolder.textInListView.setText(listStorage.get(position).getName());
    listViewHolder.imageInListView.setImageDrawable(listStorage.get(position).getIcon());
    return convertView;
}
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView textInListView;
    ImageView imageInListView;
}
  }
```

Comment: where did you save data in sharedPreference . I gone through you code but found you only accessing data from sharedPref not storing.

Comment: in Gridview adaptor "mContext.getSharedPreferences("data"

Comment: May i know how get shared preference data  base adaptor to activity

Answer (score 0):

You can either use savedInstanceState method to save and retrieve data in an Activity or You can save the boolean check value every time you change the value of your selection(either selected or non selected state) into SharedPreferences using key as name/id of the value to be selected, and value as true or false.

You can easily check the shared preferences then,  to check whether this value is present in shared preferences or not. And use Boolean value to show the selection.

Hope you get this answer.

Comment: I checking with true/false.I am getting data in base adaptor.May i know how get shared preference data base adaptor to activity

Comment: You can get it by Using context of the activity that is passed in the adapter

Comment: I am new to android...I am getting Null, But its not accpeting                          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Shared Pref-->"+selected_apps.mContext,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
may I know I going correct way??

Comment: You can access the SharedPreferences  By passing MainActivity.this as context wherever required in MainActivity class.

SharedPreferences mSettings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: @Kumar you can visit this link to understand better about preferences

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Storing-and-Accessing-SharedPreferences

Comment: Selecting favourite apps from custom list and passing to grid view.What i have select app are getting ,when i have close the application these favourite apps grid view going to clean. So  Im thinking what we are getting app name to store in shared preference.

Comment: What i have shared preference data in base adapter ,I could not able to get in the main activity.I getting little bit confession.

Comment: I have tried something like this,I cont able to save the data in array list.I have posted in above Answer